# how to use Manual Routing nativescript-vue using typescript?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-vue

How i can use the $navigationTo using typescript in nativescript-vue? i maked this work here: https://github.com/Figur8/NativescriptLoginTestVue,
but when i try with typescript i get this error.
**[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.**

```
  <template>
        <Page>
            <FlexboxLayout class="page">
                <StackLayout class="form">
                    <Image
                            src="https://www.carnegietechnologies.com/sites/ct/assets/image/logo-octopus.png"
                            loadMode="async" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>

                    <StackLayout class="input-field">
                        <TextField v-model="email" hint="email" class="input" keyboardType="email"
                                   autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none" >
                        </TextField>
                        <Label class="message" :text="email"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout class="input-field">
                        <TextField hint="Password" secure="true" class="input">
                        </TextField>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Button text="Log In" class="btn btn-primary" @tap="clientLogin" ></Button>
                    <Button text="Log In" class="btn btn-primary"
                            @tap="$goTo"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </FlexboxLayout>
        </Page>
    </template>

    <script lang="ts">

        import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';
        import {Component} from 'vue-property-decorator';
        import Home from "./Home";

        @Component
        export default class App extends Vue {
            goTo(){
                this.$navigateTo(Home);
            }
        }
    </script>

    <style scoped>
        ActionBar {
            background-color: #53ba82;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .message {
            vertical-align: center;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 20;
            color: #333333;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was make this work!, look my example.

```
<template for="r in result">
    <Page>
        <FlexboxLayout class="page">
            <StackLayout class="form">
                <Image
                        src="https://www.carnegietechnologies.com/sites/ct/assets/image/logo-octopus.png"
                        loadMode="async" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>
                <StackLayout class="input-field">
                    <TextField v-model="email" hint="email" class="input" keyboardType="email"
                               autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none" >
                    </TextField>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout class="input-field">
                    <TextField v-model="password"  hint="Password" secure="true" class="input">
                    </TextField>
                </StackLayout>
                <Button text="Log In" class="btn btn-primary" @tap="clientLogin" ></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';
    import {Component, Prop} from 'vue-property-decorator';
    import client from "@/lib/fusionAuthClientInstance";
    import Home from "@/components/Home.vue";

    const secure = {
        template: `
    <Page>
       <ActionBar title="Second" class="action-bar" />
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout class="home-panel">
                <Label>Second action action</Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Page>
  `
    };

    export interface result {
        statusCode: string,
        response: JSON,
        registration: Array<string>,
    }

    @Component
    export default class App extends Vue {

        private email: string ;
        private password: string;
        private request: Object;
        private roles: JSON;
        private user: any;
        public post: string;

        goTo(roleInFusionAuth){
            if(roleInFusionAuth == "view-security-message"){
                this.$navigateTo(Home);
            }else{
                alert({
                    title: "TRETA",
                    message: "Usuário ou senha incorretos",
                    okButtonText: "try Again"
                }).then(() => {
                    console.log("Alert dialog closed");
                });
            };

        };

        requestProvider(){
            this.request =  {
                "loginId": this.email,
                "password": this.password,
                "applicationId": "fca4814f-645c-4c3f-a9b0-2b2ca7a2e835"
            };
            return this.request;
        };

        testFusionAuthMethods() {
            return client.searchUsers("901904d8-5eeb-441f-a80e-8c8c595825b5")
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                });
        };

        clientLogin() {
            // this.$navigateTo(secure);
            return client.login(this.requestProvider())
                .then(this.handleResponse, this.handleErrorResponse)
                .then(response => {
                    this.result = response;
                    this.user = this.result.response;
                    this.roles = this.user.user.registrations;
                    this.post = this.roles[0].roles[0];
                })
                .then(responsibility =>{
                    console.log(this.post);
                    this.goTo(this.roles[0].roles[0]);
                });
        };



        handleResponse(clientResponse) {
            return clientResponse;
        };
        handleErrorResponse(clientResponse) {
            return clientResponse;
        };

        components: {
            Home,
        };
    }

</script>
<style scoped>
    ActionBar {
        background-color: #53ba82;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .message {
        vertical-align: center;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20;
        color: #333333;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is import your routes file in your component and use the key from the routes object to redirect to. For example:

routes/index.js

```
import Home from './components/Home';

export default {
    home: Home,
}
```

In your Vue component:

```
import routes from '~/routes'
export default {
    methods: {
        goTo() {
            this.$navigateTo(routes.Home)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not works for me bro! thx for your help. Look my solution.